# Is it possible to implement this design for woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have [this design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11UXpahD83I) that I want to implement: it has this button to show recommended bases for that specific product. When I google about customizing woocommerce, all I get are tutorials on how add stuff *around it*, using newbie friendly tools, such as elementor, but I want to work *in it*, adding a feature to it.

For my layman eyes, it seems like a very simple interaction: you click on a button, and it adds some elements to the page. However, since woocommerce's cart is implemented on the page through a shortcode, not an html file or whatever, I can't just edit it like I do with most stuff. I know that I have to edit some php file somewhere in the plugin's directory.

So, what I would like to know is first: is that even possible? Because I really don't want to spends days learning to code php just to find out this feature was never even a possibility to begin with.

And second: is there anything in particular I should learn to be able to do this?

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, and thank you for the attention. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this.  You would have to build a new 'template part' to replace the cart template that outputs what you're seeing in the video you posted.

A full list of all of the template parts for the WooCommerce cart view is here: 
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/3.8.0/templates

There's a really straightforward breakdown of how to override default WooCommerce templates here:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

The shortcode that goes into the page utilizes these template parts to generate the content you end up seeing on the front end.

I think the file you'd be looking to override is this one, but still, take a look at all of them and confirm that's the case:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.8.0/templates/cart/cart-item-data.php

I suspect you could use the WooCommerce related products and upsell functionality to populate the list.